# Using Aliases in a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vite, alias

I have a function responsible for constructing URLs using relative paths, such as `../../assets/images/content/recipe/`. I want to replace the `../../assets/images` part with a Vite alias, but it doesn't work.

Here's my function:

```
const getSrc = ext => {
    return new URL(
        `@img/content/recipe/${props.recipe.image}${ext}`,
        import.meta.url
    ).href;
};
```

And here's Vite config for aliases:

```
'@img': fileURLToPath(
    new URL('./src/assets/images', import.meta.url)
),
```

I'm looking for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

The URL class is a standart class in JS and not Vite. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

The way I use alias is like this:
(vite.config.js)

```
import { resolve } from 'path'

        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@img': resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/images'),
            },
        },
```

And to get a image you need to use `import`:

```js
import Image from '@img/content/recipe/img.png'
```

Another thing is that you cannot import some image that is not resolved at Vite compile time, because if you create a file called img2.png after vite compilation, your JS will not know how to get this image. You will probably need to use a server to handle these images dynamically, or provide this imagens in a public path.

If you had all the images you need in compilation time, you can import dynamically using `import.meta.glob('@img/content/*.png')` and get the correct image using a search.

https://vitejs.dev/guide/features#glob-import

Comment: The Vite config for alies that I provided comes by default from when creating a new project with `npm init vue@latest`. It works same as if using `resolve`. Also, I store the image name in the database and then I pass this name as a `prop.recipe.image` to the URL. I store images locally in `./src/assets/images`. What if I try to place the images in a public directory, will it be accessible at runtime?

Comment: Maybe you could try this: 
`{ find: '@img', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/image') },` in resolve.alias, this should work.

Comment: @Crazyends I can see these two properties in the `Alias` object, but if I add the object like this `resolve: {alias: { { find: '@img', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/image') } }}`, nothing seem to work.